# Cron job not working after CIVICRM update (Joomla 3.7.0 and CIVICRM

Tags: civimail

we used to send emails to members with great succes before.
Now, I've upgraded the site's Joomla and CIVICRM versions, prepared a draft email, but started to receive emails from the system about a bad configuration, her's the message:

**Warning**:  ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in **/home/XXX/public_html/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php** on line **46**
 
 **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function get() on null in **/home/XXX/public_html/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php** on line **71**

I tried to execute the cron by entering the URL in a browser (wich worked before the upgrades) but I get the same error.

So what should I look after? I tried to see by myself and looked in forums, but can't nail how to have it work out.

Thanks for your help!

Marc.

Comment: For reference working on fixes here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11609

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the first thing to do is try to isolate the issue (or clarify it): did civicrm work before upgrading to Joomla 3.7, it was it civicrm that you had upgraded (what was the exact upgrade that broke the cron jobs).

It's strange because those errors look more like a session cache issue.

Did you try the "run all scheduled jobs" link from the jobs page?

Are you executing with a user that had the needed permissions?

Comment: Hi Randy, thanks for your reply. I upgraded Joomla AND CiviCRM at the same time so can't nail anything with that...

I ran the "send emails" script from within CiviCRM and all is working right, but when I try even the web page, I get that error message. 

Paul Kleingeld maybe has something: there maybe a bug in Joomla 3.7. I'll wait for an update and until then I'll send from the CiviCRM page.

Thanks and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too after upgrading to Joomla 3.7.0 on a CiviCRM 4.7.18 installation that was previously working fine.
I don't see the errors you describe, only the civi pop-up message saying cron is not running.
Running all scheduled jobs works fine.

Comment: It seems that in Joomla 3.7 an issue has risen that interferes with cron; see: https://www.akeebabackup.com/home/news/1676-joomla-3-7-0-and-cli-scripts.html

Comment: Thanks Paul. I went to see and looks like I'll wait for the update! Thanks, Marc.

Comment: This is interesting. I skimmed the article. The thing that confuses me is that cron is a script scheduler. It really shouldn't affect how a page is rendered. If Joomla 3.7 has a bug with cron, it should affect how jobs are run. I'll have to ready up on this more closely. Either way, I hope they get it patched soon.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the Warning: ini_set(): error, which I've experienced on my site for several updates of civiCRM I have to comment out, 'ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '0');' in the joomla.php file. Doing this has resolved my CRON not working issue every time, except for the latest update of Joomla to 3.7 and PHP to 7.0. Now, after commenting out the above referenced line, I'm getting the following error, 'Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Call to a member function get() on null' which I've not been able to resolve. I've posted it here as a question ([Cron job not working after CIVICRM update (Joomla 3.7.0 and CIVICRM](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18396/cron-job-not-working-after-civicrm-update-joomla-3-7-0-and-civicrm)) a few days ago, but have not received a response.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by a Joomla 3.7.0 bug. See https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/15605 The patch therein works OK for me (libraries/joomla/factory.php).