# Cron Job returning 404 in Joomla

Tags: joomla, cron-job

This is a new install CiviCRM 4.7.29 on Joomla! 3.8.3 on Hostgator Shared.
The Cron File is returning a 404 Error message.
I can access the file itself when I run it from the Cpanel but somehow it is returning this error.

I changed the permissions on the Bin folder and cron.php (755,755) as was suggested in another post but still no success.

I created a specific user/group with the suggested permission just for the cron job. But now I'm testing with the Super Admin.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Update: I commented out: 'ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '0');' in joomla.php file which fixed the error and the Cron Job is now working. (as posted [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18396/cron-job-not-working-after-civicrm-update-joomla-3-7-0-and-civicrm))
However. I'm not sure how this change might affect other functions in Joomla.

Comment: I started having a different error: Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in  ...
Nothing has changed but now I have this error

Answer (score 1):

I commented out: 'ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '0');' in joomla.php file which fixed the error and the Cron Job is now working. (as posted [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18396/cron-job-not-working-after-civicrm-update-joomla-3-7-0-and-civicrm)) However. I'm not sure how this change might affect other functions in Joomla.

Comment: If anyone is still having this problem with cron.php (not cli.php) and getting either `Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "yoursite/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php"` OR `Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session` **could you please test this Joomla patch?**:
https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/21260. Just one more human test is required and then we might finally get this issue fixed! https://docs.joomla.org/Testing_Joomla!_patches#Recording_test_results